# Wix - remove admin-page

Tags: velo

I added an admin-page(Dashboardpage) on my wix-website via "Add Page"...
By accident I added two more pages as shown in the screenshot, and now they appear
in my backend. How can I remove these two empty pages?
I dont find any information about that on the official website. A regular Site can be deleted simply.

Thanks for your help

[image: I want to remove the "New Page" entries.]

[image: There is no option to manipulate/delete the pages]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Admin pages can be deleted by enabling the **Velo Dev Mode**

1. Enabling Dev Mode

[image: 1]

2. Delete Option

[image: 2]